# SQL get the value of the latest preceding row matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a CTE with these columns that looks like this table:

```sql
create table example (
rn int, --generated row number
id int,
start_value int,
end_value int,
starts_chunk int --1 starts a new chunk, 0 means the chunk is continued
);
```

I want to add another column, `chunk_start_value`, that contains the `start_value` of the current chunk.

The following

```sql
select *
, (select start_value
   from example em
   where rn = (
     select max(rn))
     from example ei
     where rn <= eo.rn
     and starts_chunk = 1
   )
  ) chunk_start_value
from example eo
```

is something that's just too many nested loops for the DBMS to handle, as there are about 400k rows in the `example` CTE.

I can't have a self-referential windowing function that does this (which is what I would have done in Excel):

```sql
select *
, case
    when starts_chunk = 1 then start_value
    else lag(chunk_start_value) over (order by rn)
  end chunk_start_value
from example
```

I can't materialize any intermediate result into a temp table, or I would have done that to rows that start chunks and indexed it.

Can I even do what I need in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `case` expression as an argument and `ignore nulls` addition of analytic functions to skip values that are continuation of a chunk:

```
select
  e.*
  , last_value(decode(starts_chunk, 1, rn)) ignore nulls
      over(order by rn) as start_chunk_rn
from example e
order by rn asc
```

| RN | ID | START_VALUE | END_VALUE | STARTS_CHUNK | START_CHUNK_RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 | 8 | 0 | 6 |
| 8 | 8 | 5 | 6 | 0 | 6 |
| 9 | 9 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 6 |
| 10 | 10 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 6 |
| 11 | 11 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 11 |
| 12 | 12 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 11 |
| 13 | 13 | 9 | 6 | 0 | 11 |
| 14 | 14 | 6 | 5 | 0 | 11 |
| 15 | 15 | 3 | 9 | 0 | 11 |
| 16 | 16 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 16 |
| 17 | 17 | 9 | 3 | 0 | 16 |
| 18 | 18 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 16 |
| 19 | 19 | 2 | 9 | 0 | 16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uRgJVFRs)